# Spring boot change default embedded server to Weblogic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, weblogic

It is quite easy change the default embedded server from tomcat to jetty and undertow. Is there any way to make weblogic as embedded server , I mean can we make weblogic work same way tomcat does?

Now I use tomcat as my development server, then I make some changes to make it compatible to run the war file in weblogic.

Is there any way we can embed the weblogic server in our spring boot dev enviornment?

Comment: No. As it is a full blown EE server. What is wrong with using Tomcat or Jetty in the first place. You don't need anything that is provided by Weblogic aparently.

Comment: I don't think Weblogic provides a embedded API.

Comment: A 1 gigabyte embedded server... nice idea.

Comment: WebLogic Server needs a domain configuration to run instances.
Don't forget about the license also...